# Dapper, pass parameter from method argument to query Where clause

Tags: .net-core, dapper

I have just started looking a Dapper targeting .Net Core but i'm having an issue with the following query,

```
   string query = @"
 SELECT u.*, a.* FROM [System].[UnLocation] u
INNER JOIN [Declaration].[AirTransportZone] a ON [u].[AirTransportZoneID] = 
[a].[AirTransportZoneID]
WHERE u.Code = @0 ";
        IUnLocationData domain = new UnLocationData();
   IQueryable<UnLocationData> data =  m_DbConnection.Query<UnLocationData, AirTransportZoneData, UnLocationData>(
           query,
            (u, a) =>
        {
            u.AirTransportZone = a;
            return u;
        },
            splitOn: "AirTransportZoneID"
            ).AsQueryable();

        domain.InjectFrom(data);

        return domain;
```

The above sits within a method that takes a single argument "code" of type string. I simply need to pass the method value of "code" into my query. Normally I would just do something like

```
WHERE u.Code = @0, code
```

however adding another parameter after my query variable (query, code...) does not work.

Answer (score -1):

My solution turned out to be reasonably straight forward. It was a simple case of adding another argument top the Query function:

new { Code = code }

```
 string query = @"
SELECT u.*, a.* FROM [System].[UnLocation] u
INNER JOIN [Declaration].[AirTransportZone] a ON [u].[AirTransportZoneID] = 
[a].[AirTransportZoneID]
WHERE u.Code = @Code";

        IUnLocationData domain = new UnLocationData();
        IEnumerable<UnLocationData> data = m_DbConnection.Query<UnLocationData, AirTransportZoneData, UnLocationData>(
            query, (u, a) =>
            {
                u.AirTransportZone = a;
                return u;
            },
            new { Code = code }, splitOn: "AirTransportZoneID"
            );
```

Comment: @VMAtm idk. Wasn't me